# Connecting n keys to n safes in minimal number of attempts

Tags: combinatorics, computational-complexity

Suppose I have $n$ safes and $n$ keys "arranged in random succession", each safe unlockable by exactly one of those keys. To find out which key belongs to which safe I am allowed to try unlock a safe with one of the keys: such an attempt is counted as one "turn".

I know that if I try to match the first key with the first safe, try to match it with the 2nd safe if that first attempt failed, try to match it with the 3rd safe if that 2nd attempt failed,..., try to match it to safe no. $n-1$ if the $n-2$'nd attempt failed, then after at most $n-1$ turns I can locate the safe belonging to the first key. Hence, I can situate the 2nd key in $n-2$ turns, the 3rd key in $n-3$ turns,..., key no. $n-1$ in $1$ turn and the final key is associated to the final remaining safe and requires no turn. To conclude: there's clearly a strategy which permits a solution to this problem requiring $(n-1)+(n-2)+...+1+0=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ turns in the worst-case scenario.

**Is it possible to arrive with a better strategy, as measured in the no. of turns in the worst-case scenario? If not, how to prove that $n(n-1)/2$ is the optimal number of turns required in the worst case?**

Addendum: one comment hinted the possibility that there's just "the number of turns in the worst-case scenario" in stead of the "optimal number of turns in the worst-case scenario". To partially address this comment, let me give an example of a strategy (which is "bona-fide" in the sense that every turn consists of trying a key-vs-safe pair that wasn't attempted before and we still allow to match safes with keys "by elimination") whose worst-case performance is worse than $n(n-1)/2$. Here it goes:

*First we try to match key $1$ to safe $1$, then key $2$ to safe $2$,..., key $n$ to safe $n$

*Next, we try to match key $1$ to safe $2$, then key $2$ to safe $3$,..., then key $n-1$ to safe $n$ and then key $n$ to safe $1$.

*...

*Next we try to match key $1$ to safe $n-1$, then key $2$ to safe $n$, key $3$ to safe $1$,...,key $n$ to safe $n-2$.

Now, if the keys and safes were arranged so that key $1$ were matched to safe $n$, key $2$ to safe $1$, key 3 to safe $2$,..., key $n$ to safe $n-1$, we would have spent $n(n-1)$ turns before determining which key is matched to which safe.

Comment: There is **no optimal** number of turns required in the worst case. This is just the number of turns required in the worst case.

Comment: I think you may be able to do it with an adversarial approach.  Instead of trying the keys in the locks, you ask me, "Will key $m$ open lock $n$?" but I lie, in order to make the process take as many turns as possible.  I think it's true that I can always make it take ${n\choose2}$ turns. Of course, whatever lies I tell, as long as I don't contradict myself, this correspond to a possible outcome of the trials.

Comment: @saulspatz: I don't understand the essence of your comment. Anyway, in this problem I don't allow there to be a "you" and "me". The only action available to you to solve the problem is matching one of your keys to one of the safes (one at a time)

Comment: It's the same problem.  Read the comment again.

Comment: @callculus: no, associated to each strategy one can conceive to attack and solve this problem there is a set of "worst-case scenarios": in these scenarios the keys and boxes are presented to you in such a succession/configuration that your strategy will perform poorest among all possible configurations. Not all possible strategies require the same number of turns in their worst case scenario. There are strategies which minimize the number of turns in their worst case scenario.

Comment: The problem isn't clear. If safes/keys are randomly ordered, there is no "optimal" solution. Each pairing has an equal chance. You say that the keys and safes are presented to you in a certain succession. If both are presented to you in a given succession, there is no point of talking about strategy because you have no choice. If you are to find the safe a single key belongs to, then it is just one of the random order, so again there is no optimal solution because of equal chances. The question that'd be meaningful is given a strategy how to arrange the safes for the longest game.

Comment: @Norbert: I might agree with you if the goal were to find the safe associated to one of the keys. In the problem at hand however, we have to find the safe for *all* of the keys: after I've made one or a few attempts with the first key, the probabilities for pairing of the 2nd key with a given safe are no longer equal for all the safes.

Comment: @ThibautDemaerel: They are. Let's call the first game the number of trials you need to make to find the first safe/key pairing. In this game, each pairing has 1/n probability. Then it becomes recursive. The second game is the same as the first because the conditional probabilities given that you tried the 1st key with any of the safes in the 1st game does not change the probability that the 2nd key matches to any of the remaining safes. So in the second game all the pairing has probability 1/(n-1) and so on.

Comment: You assume there already that the most efficient way to proceed is first to locate the safe for the first key, then the safe for the second...thus casting aside any strategy that attempts to gather a mixed bag of information by interlacing attempts with key 1 by attempts with other keys. You have to prove the assertion that these alternative strategies do not lead to a lower number of turns in the worst case scenario.

Comment: Okay, so if I can try any of the keys with any of the safes randomly, then I don't understand your comment about keys/safes being present in random succession. If I can try them in any order, then there is no succession. I can pick both of them from a bag without ordering. If I assume, that the turns are independent, then you got your result. If the turns are not independent (which you imply), then you need to provide more information about their dependence to come up with a better strategy. Without knowing that, you can practically assume that they are random.

Comment: @norbertk Here the setup; you are given n keys and n safes, and each key opens a distinct unknown safe. For each move, you may try to open **any** safe with **any** key. You seem to be assuming you have to try the first key, then the second, and so on, in which case $n(n-1)/2$ is obviously optimal, but the question is asking if you can speed this up by changing up the order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can prove $\binom{n}2$ tests is optimal using Hall's marriage theorem, specifically the following generalization, due to [Marshall Hall Jr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem#Marshall_Hall_Jr._variant):

> Suppose you have a collection of sets $A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n$, which satisfies:
>
> - **Hall condition:** For any $I\subseteq \{1,2,\dots,n\}$, $\left|\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i\right|\ge |I|$.
> - Each $|A_i|\ge r$, for some number $r\le n$.
>
> Then there exists a way to select from each set $A_i$ an element $a_i$ such that the elements $a_i$ are pairwise distinct. Furthermore, this can be done in at least $r!$ ways.

Suppose that you have performed fewer than $\binom{n}2$ tests. Further suppose that none of those tests were successful. This is a valid assumption; once you have deduced a key goes in a lock, there is no reason to test it. Therefore, for every test you make in an optimal strategy, there must be a possibility that the key you test did not unlock that safe, so in the worst case all tests are unsuccessful.

Assume that no key was tested $n-1$ times. I claim this implies you cannot deduce the true assignment. If you let $K_i$ be the set of safes you have not tested the $i^{th}$ key on, then a valid assignment exists, implying Hall's condition is fulfilled, and by assumption each $|K_i|\ge 2$. We have verified both conditions of the above proposition, so at least $2!$ assignments exist. Therefore, if you *can* deduce the assignment, some key must have been tested $n-1$ times, meaning you know what safe it goes in. What remains are $n-1$ keys to be matched with $n-1$ safes, which have been tested fewer than $\binom{n}2-(n-1)=\binom{n-1}2$ times. By induction, we can conclude there is more than one valid assignment.

Comment: Your last paragraph looks very promising. Before accepting your answer, let me still ponder to understand the Hall lemma or perhaps simplify things so that it is no longer needed (in full force).